# How do I re-add a game to Steam? I have the data files and the ncf file?

Tags: steam

Before I realised Steam had a backup option, I tried to manually back up my games.

For my game I have the NCF file, and the Game data (the folder from Steam/steamapps/common).

I have done the following

1. I put the NCF file in Steam/steamapps
2. I put the game folder in Steam/steamapps/common
3. I restarted my computer

Steam still thinks the game is not installed and is trying to make me redownload it.

**Is there a way I can let Steam know the game is there?**

*Note: I live in Australia, and we have download limits, so I don't want to redownload my whole game again.*

Comment: aw man, +1 for internet limits

Answer (score 0):

I found a dup question here -> [How to get Steam to recognize existing game files from a different source?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97330/how-to-get-steam-to-recognize-existing-game-files-from-a-different-source)

So I just clicked install, and it worked.

The game was Deus Ex: Human revolution.

What is weird, is with Shogun 2 it didn't work and I had to download 30ish gig again for that game. Though with that game I didn't have the ncf file. So maybe that is needed?

Comment: You don't need to add this as an answer. Mods can close this question as a duplicate of the one you provided.